# Force a loop to wait two functions run sequentially

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, async-await

I have two functions that must be invoked sequentially within a loop, which in the code will loop 3 times. In the second function I have some animations and I do not know how to make the loop wait for the animation of the second function to end so that the loop goes to the next iteration.

LOOP FUNCTION

```
function startGame(){
  emptyTab();

  $("#movimentos-text").html(0)
  $('.time').show()
  $('.painel-tabuleiro').show();
  $(".btn-reinicio").text("Reiniciar")


  for(var i = 0; i < 3; i ++){
    generateRandomCandys()
    emptyElements()
  }

}
```

FIRST FUNCTION

```
function generateRandomCandys(){
    var elements = $(".painel-tabuleiro").children("div");

    for (var i = 1; i <= elements.length; i++) {
      for (var j = elements[i-1].childElementCount; j < 7; j++) {
        //... some logic
        }
      }
    }
}
```

SECOND FUNCTION

```
function emptyElements(){
    // ... some logic
    $(".equalElement").fadeOut()
    $(".equalElement").fadeIn()
    $(".equalElement").fadeOut()
    $(".equalElement").fadeIn()
    $(".equalElement").fadeOut(function() {
      $(".equalElement").remove()
    })
}
```

I've already tried using async and await, promise, interval and timeout but nothing worked.
I want to know how to do this:

```
 for(var i = 0; i < 3; i ++){
    run first: generateRandomCandys()
    run second: emptyElements()
    wait the emptyElements() animations finish to increase i
}
```

Comment: Your `emptyElements` is calling `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` over and over again *synchronously*, are you sure that's what you want? Seems a bit pointless

Comment: *" I do not know how to make the loop wait for the animation"* You cannot. `for` loops as inherently synchronous. Instead you need to use some kind of recursion: `function doWork(i) { /* wait for async stuff */ if (i < 2) { doWork(i); } }; doWork(0);` `emptyElements` should accept a callback to notify the caller when it is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are OK with using `await` then you could chain the jQuery `.promise()` method, like this:

```
async function startGame(){
//^^^^
  emptyTab();

  $("#movimentos-text").html(0)
  $('.time').show()
  $('.painel-tabuleiro').show();
  $(".btn-reinicio").text("Reiniciar")

  for(var i = 0; i < 3; i ++){
    generateRandomCandys()
    await emptyElements()
  //^^^^^
  }
}
```

Second function:

```
async function emptyElements(){
//^^^^
    return $(".equalElement").fadeOut().fadeIn().fadeOut().fadeIn().fadeOut()
    //^^^^
                      .promise().then(()=> $(".equalElement").remove())
                    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some sort of recursion as *@Felix Kling* suggested.

Then, to avoid triggering the callback for every `.equalElement` object, use [`$.when()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/):

> Provides a way to execute callback functions based on zero or more Thenable objects, usually Deferred objects that represent asynchronous events.

```js
var iteration = 0;

function showCandys() {
  generateRandomCandys();
  emptyElements();
}

function generateRandomCandys() {
  $("div div").each(function() {
    if (Math.random() <= 0.5) {
      var candy = $("<span></span>").text("CANDY").addClass("equalElement");
      $(this).append(candy);
    }
  });
}

function emptyElements() {
  $.when($(".equalElement").fadeIn().fadeOut().fadeIn().fadeOut()).then(function() {
    $(".equalElement").remove();
    iteration++;
    if (iteration < 3) showCandys();
  })
}

showCandys();
```

```css
div div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```